# Export to excel using Java not workingi n IE10

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem in opening excel sheet in IE10 .In my project I will be generating a report after selecting a specific department and when I click on open to open the report it will open in the excel format with the name ConstraintReport.xls . When I click another department and give generate report it should open in the name ConstarintReport(1).xls . But its throwing a error stating **"Cannot open two files with the same name"** . What can be done ??

```
         if(mode != null && mode.equalsIgnoreCase(TLOConstants.REPORT_CONTROL)){
        List controlList = getReportService().getControlReportList(reportsVO);  
        if(controlList.size()!=0){
            resultArray1 = controlReportFormatList(controlList); 
            byteArrayStream = WorkbookUtil.generateControlPlanReport(resultArray1);
            excelSheet = TLOConstants.CONTROL_REPORT;
            openExcel = true;
        }
    }

  if(openExcel==true){
        response.setHeader(TLOConstants.CACHE_CTRL, TLOConstants.PUBLIC);
        response.setHeader(TLOConstants.PRAGMA, TLOConstants.PUBLIC);
        response.setHeader(TLOConstants.EXPIRES,TLOConstants.ZERO);
        response.setHeader(TLOConstants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, TLOConstants.ATTACH_FILE_NAME +               excelSheet + ".xls\";");
        response.setContentType(TLOConstants.APPLICATION_VNDMS_XLS);
        if (byteArrayStream != null) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(byteArrayStream.toByteArray());
        }
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        byteArrayStream.close();

        logMethodExit(TLOConstants.ON_SUBMIT);
        return null;
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. There is a missing double quote in the content-disposition line. There is also a typo in the content; its 'attachment', not 'attachement'.

Comment: No I just typed those code.It isn't a problem .It is compiling .I have edited the codeiwth excat variables.Am taking those variables from TLOConstants file .Hope ypu could understand .

Comment: Don't do that. If you want help with code, post -your- code, not "code that looks like your code". Until then its a guessing game what your real problem is. And now I'm going to assume the constant values are wrong until you show that code too.

Comment: Try "Content Disposition" header with "inline" instead of "attachment"

Comment: @jbaliuka I tried inline its not working .I have changed the code added timestamp to the filename .But its opening as ten different files with diff timestamp I want to open in the same excel sheet .How can tat be done ??